# ArrayStoreException for no reason?

Tags: java, file, exception

I am trying to make classes to do the following:
Get a folder, get what folder it contains, and for each folder that is in the main folder - get the files in it and move them into two groups - ones that are mp4, mkv, vlc and avi types and ones that are srt types.

My current code is:

Show.class: http://pastebin.com/vZ7ipFJc

Season.class: http://pastebin.com/tqUJ7S9v

Main.class: http://pastebin.com/LaEvuARW

The stacktrace leads me to many different places:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(Unknown Source)
at Show.<init>(Show.java:47)
at Main.getShows(Main.java:24)
at Main.setupShowsBox(Main.java:70)
at Main.<init>(Main.java:96)
at Main.main(Main.java:54)
```

(The lines in pastebin are the same as in code) And the problem seems to be where I convert the arraylist into an array, and I dont know what the problem **is**. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Post your **relevant** code here. No one wants to follow links.

Comment: Post your code here, If those links breaks this question becomes garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this line 47 in Show.java:

```
this.seasonsFile=seasons.toArray(new File[seasons.size()])
```

`seasons` is an `ArrayList` of `Season`.  `ArrayList#toArray` is not going to be able to squeeze a load of `Season`s into an array of `File`s.  Maybe you wanted `this.seasonsFile = seasons.getShows;`?

Also, you shouldn't have package private variable names following the convention of method names.  It's going to confuse everyone.

Comment: Thank you very much! I looked at the code a lot of times and didn't notice that, I meant to do this.seasonsFile=seasonsFile.toArray(new File[seasonsFile.size()]);

Comment: Are you sure?  That doesn't seem likely either.

Comment: Yes, I am sure, this works because seasonsFile is an arraylist and this.seasosnFile is a File array. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

So here's the line causing the error:

```
List<Season> seasons;
File[] seasonFile;

this.seasonsFile=seasons.toArray(new File[seasons.size()]);
```

You're trying to convert a list of `Season`s to an array of `File`s. You can convert a list of `File`s to an array of `File`s, or you can convert a list of `Season`s to an array of `Season`s using `toArray()`.

If you have a way of converting `Season` objects to `File` objects you could put that in a `toFile()` method on your `Season` object. Then to get your file array:

```
int idx = 0;
for (season : seasons) {
    seasonsFile[idx] = season.toFile();
    idx++;
}
```